# Deleting rows with differents with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm trying to delete some rows in a DB and I'm blocking on my request. The table where I want to delete those rows looks like that:

[image]

In this example, I must delete the rows no. 1 and 5.
The request has to be like, the rows is the last row in a group of msg_id (the same msg_id). The last is given by "A". To delete this row, in the same group msg_id, and between the rows of the same msg_id, "B" has to have the same value, but "D" must be different. I hope my explanation is clear.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Your explanation is very unclear

Comment: Okay, here are the conditions : 1. Has to be in a group of msg_id (more than on row has to have the same msg_id). 2. has to be the the higher value of "A". 3. The "B" must be the same value in all rows of the group of msg_id, 3. "C" must be different. hope is clear this time

Comment: Is it more clear?

Comment: i think i get it, is it where `msg_id` is the same, `A` is higher, and `B` the same?

Comment: Exactly, and C must be different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
DELETE
FROM   my_table AS tab1
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   my_table tab2
               WHERE  tab1.msg_id = tab2.msg_id
                 AND  tab1.A > tab2.A
                 AND  tab1.B = tab2.B
                 AND  tab1.C <> tab2.C)
  AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   my_table tab3
                   WHERE  tab1.msg_id = tab3.msg_id
                     AND  tab1.A < tab3.A
                     AND  tab1.B = tab3.B
                     AND  tab1.C <> tab3.C);
```

Comment: I see, but if there is more than two entry with the same msg_id, it will delete 2 rows yes? And I need just the one with the biggest A. Does it work?

Comment: add grouping by msg id then select order by A desc within groups and take the first from each group.

Comment: I updated my answer. It's not really elegant but it should work

Comment: can you explain  me why the not exists?

Comment: In order to make sure we're deleting only the row with the highest value of A

Comment: Oh ok thank you, I'm looking now for the selection of the first of each group, is it with the function row_number()?

Comment: What do you mean with "the first of each group"?

Comment: I mean to get the first row when I grouped with msg_id